# Possible to take hash from know result and algorithm?

Tags: hash, php, reverse-engineering, sha256

I am trying to build a casino site in PHP where users can play roulette. I found this algorithm that I want to use to "roll" numbers:

```
<?php
$secret = 'aa94c4384abc04456c45459cdedf1120f2cc0ac09bc4724322b6831bd7f43d6f';
$round = 123456;
$hash = hash("sha256",$secret.'-'.$round);
$roll = hexdec(substr($hash, 0, 8)) % 37;
echo($roll);
?>
```

The result will be 22 in this example.

- `secret` is sha256 hash
- `round` is the number of played rounds, where every spin will +1

I'm worried that someone that knows the algorithm will be able to reverse it to take the hash.

Is this solution good? (I'm a beginner to this kind of problems.)

Comment: Exactly what is your goal here? To generate a random number? If so, why not use [random_int](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php)?

Answer (score 5):

OK, so the first issue is: **do you need these rolls to be reproducible and predictable?**  That is, do you need to be able to fast-forward to the 10000th roll or rewind to the 20th, and get the same result?

If you don't need that feature, then why not use a [cryptographically secure random number generator instead](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php)?  This way, *neither you nor an attacker* can predict the results, and you don't have to worry about accidentally revealing your secret at any point.

*(If you **do** want that feature, I think it's really worth asking why.  Would your users be happy with the idea that all results are predetermined, just kept secret?  There's also a slight bias in your implementation, and you have the extra challenge of keeping your secret a secret, etc. etc. etc.)*